# How to recognize a repeating pattern in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

If I have an array like

`const arr = [1, 5, 7, 5, 13, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7];`

What would be the best way of finding that the array starts to repeat itself? In this instance that the first three numbers and the last three numbers are in a repeating pattern.

This is a random array, the repeating could easily start at index 365 and not necessarily from the first index.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the pattern could be any length, so a minimum of 2 numbers but no maximum?

Comment: what do you want to do if the array has repeating elements?

Comment: the pattern could be any length, but if there are already two numbers, in my case, that's a repeating pattern. In that case just returning false or -1 would be the desired result

Comment: So if you match a pattern of 2 characters then it can stop?  No need to check for more.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you're looking for...

```js
const arr1 = [1, 5, 7, 5, 13, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7];
const arr2 = [1, 5, 7, 5, 13, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 4, 7];

function patternFound(arr) {
  var newArray = arr.map(function(o, i) {
      if (i < arr.length - 1) {
        return arr[i] + "|" + arr[i + 1];
      }
    })
    .sort();

  newArray = newArray.filter(function(o, i) {
      if (i < arr.length - 1) {
       return (o == newArray[i + 1]);
      }
    });

  return newArray.length > 0;
}

console.log(patternFound(arr1));
console.log(patternFound(arr2));
```

Basically, it creates an array of paired elements from the first array, with a pipe delimiter `(["1|5", "5|7", "7|5" etc.])`, sorts it and then looks for duplicates by comparing each element to the next.

There's probably a much smaller way of doing this, but I didn't want to spend time making something that was unreadable.  This does what you want and does it simply and clearly.

The first array is the one you supplied, and the second has been changed so there's no matching pattern.

Comment: No worries - happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single loop approach with short circuit and a hash table for found pairs like

> ```
> {
>     "1|5": true,
>     "5|7": true,
>     "7|5": true,
>     "5|13": true,
>     "13|8": true,
>     "8|1": true,
>     "1|7": true,
>     "7|3": true,
>     "3|8": true,
>     "8|5": true,
>     "5|2": true,
>     "2|1": true
> }
> ```

The iteration stops immediately on index `12` with the other found pair `1|5`.

```js
function check(array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    return array.some(function (v, i, a) {
        var pair = [v, a[i + 1]].join('|');
        return hash[pair] || !(hash[pair] = true);
    });
}

console.log(check([1, 5, 7, 5, 13, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7])); //  true
console.log(check([1, 5, 7, 5, 13, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 3, 7])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop seems the simplest approach.

Make sure to offset the nested loop to save calculations:

```js
/**
 * Takes array and returns either boolean FALSE or the first index of a pattern
 *
 * @param {any[]} arr
 * @returns {(false | number)}
 */
function findArrayPattern(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var point1 = 0; point1 < arr.length - 2; point1++) {
    var p1 = arr[point1];
    var p2 = arr[point1 + 1];
    for (var point2 = point1 + 2; point2 < arr.length - 1; point2++) {
      var p3 = arr[point2];
      var p4 = arr[point2 + 1];
      if (p1 == p3 && p2 == p4) {
        return point1;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
//TEST
var arr = [1, 5, 7, 5, 13, 8, 1, 7, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7];
var pattern = findArrayPattern(arr);
if (pattern !== false) {
  console.log("a pattern was found at " + pattern);
} else {
  console.log("no pattern was found");
}
```